# PyInstaller ErroNo2 "No such file or directory: 'akespec'"

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Errno2 seems to be a common error for PyInstaller but I am afraid none of the results on this site are talking about this particular file/directory. I suspect there is a "typo" somewhere which is leading PyInstaller to read the file name as "akespec" rather than "makespec"

The log from Traceback is here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main

    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 9, i
n <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", lin
e 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", lin
e 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_ma
in.py", line 838, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'
))
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_ma
in.py", line 784, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 31, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py",
 line 410, in __init__
    self.console, self.uac_admin, self.uac_uiaccess)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winma
nifest.py", line 1047, in create_manifest
    manifest = ManifestFromXMLFile(manifest)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winma
nifest.py", line 999, in ManifestFromXMLFile
    manifest.parse(filename_or_file)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winma
nifest.py", line 741, in parse
    domtree = minidom.parse(filename_or_file)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 1958, in parse
    return expatbuilder.parse(file)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 910, in pars
e
    with open(file, 'rb') as fp:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'akespec'
```

How should I go about rectifying this?

Thanks
Soham

Comment: It looks like you are missing a resource files from a module. Try adding the missing directory under `data` in the spec file.
https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html

Comment: The spec file has a typo.  Value of manifest in spec file should be **makespec**.

Comment: Yes indeed, there was a problem. But it now says the same thing with "No such file or directory: 'makespec' "

Comment: I edited the manifest value to point to the actual manifest of the script. Worked

Answer (score 1):

Via some help from @narendra-choudhary, I figured out that the main issue was in the spec file.

First changing the value of `manifest` from 'akespec' to 'makespec' simplified the error log.

The error log still said- "No such file or directory: 'makespec' ".

So I manually edited the `manifest` value to point to build directory and the right manifest file.

It ultimately generated a perfectly working exe in dist folder.

Comment: could you please give an example to elaborate more on what you did. I have managed to change the manifest value to 'makespec' but  I can't seem to understand what you mean by changing the manifest value to point to build directory, please elaborate some more